# how can I change the position of TabLayout in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-tablayout

So, I am my tabs in a Tablayout below the TopAppBar but I want these tabs to be on the left side of the screen and not at the Top. I even tried to chnage the Alignment to Alignment.Start but nothing changes. Below is my code

```
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun TableLayout(){

    var tabIndex by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    val tabs = listOf<String>("Basic","Medium","Hard")

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
        TabRow(selectedTabIndex = tabIndex,
        modifier = Modifier.align(androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Start)) {
            tabs.forEachIndexed{ index,title ->
                Tab(text = { Text(title) },
                    selected = tabIndex == index,
                    onClick = { tabIndex = index }
                )
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

[image] As you can see images one below other. So instead of that I want the tabs of tab layout one below others instead of those images.

Comment: can you please add your expected image if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try using horizontalArrangement in TabRow instead of align in its modifier to arrange its content horizontally.

EDIT: See this article for more details on alignment vs. arrangement
https://semicolonspace.com/jetpack-compose-alignment-arrangement/

EDIT: This code will arrange them one on top of another, vertically instead of the horizontal layout you have now. (if that is what you are looking for). Otherwise please specify your desired layout in more detail.

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
        TabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = tabIndex.value,
            modifier = Modifier.align(androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Start,
            )
        ) {
            Column() {
                tabs.forEachIndexed{ index,title ->
                    Tab(text = { Text(title) },
                        selected = tabIndex.value == index,
                        onClick = { tabIndex.value = index }
                    )
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you edit my code and paste it or just the line ?

Comment: Sure, no problem. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: .value codes are showing error , unresolved reference